# I use latest Android Studio 4.1.2 version (Android Gradle plugin 4.1.2) I have problem with adding lifecycle library (for DataBinding)

Tags: android, data-binding, android-lifecycle

I have problem with adding lifecycle library (for DataBinding) to my project and  .

implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:2.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'

Error Gradle:xecution failed for task ':app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find lifecycle-extensions-2.2.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0).

please help me.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

To enable Data Binding in your project, just add the following code inside `android` block inside your app-level gradle file. Nothing else is required to enable Data Binding. This is sufficient. After you add this, sync your project and also click on **File** menu in Android Studio and then click **Invalidate Caches and Restart** and then you should be able to use data binding.

```
android 
{

    ...

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
}
```

And secondly please note that, officially the APIs in `lifecycle-extensions` have been deprecated. Instead, add dependencies for the specific Lifecycle artifacts you need from the following list. There is no need to add all of the below dependencies, you can add only specific dependencies based on your requirement.

```
dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
    def arch_version = "2.1.0"

    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // Lifecycles only (without ViewModel or LiveData)
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"

    // Saved state module for ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:$lifecycle_version"

    // Annotation processor
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
    // alternately - if using Java8, use the following instead of lifecycle-compiler
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"

    // optional - helpers for implementing LifecycleOwner in a Service
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:$lifecycle_version"

    // optional - ProcessLifecycleOwner provides a lifecycle for the whole application process
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:$lifecycle_version"

    // optional - ReactiveStreams support for LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-reactivestreams-ktx:$lifecycle_version"

    // optional - Test helpers for LiveData
    testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$arch_version"
}
```